# SQL loop through check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm having a slight issue creating an SQL query.
I have a table with 4 columns `'Enquiry Date' , 'Taken Date' , 'Indication Date' , 'Cancelled Date'` the table is called `tbl_Sales`.

What i would like to do is create a bit a t-sql that says look at the 4 columns and whatever one has the closest date to `GETDATE()` is the current status.

So for instance if the row has a date in each column and the last date that was filled in was say yesterday in the `'Cancelled Date'` then the status for that row should show as `canceled`.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What if `'Enquiry Date' , 'Taken Date' , 'Indication Date'` have same date and closest to `Getdate()`?

Comment: Hi Deepshikha i didnt think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some bad design if you don't have some status field. Here is bruteforce solution:

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN [Cancelled Date] IS NOT NULL AND 
                  ([Cancelled Date] > [Indication Date] OR [Indication Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Cancelled Date] > [Taken Date] OR [Taken Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Cancelled Date] > [Enquiry Date] OR [Enquiry Date] IS NULL) THEN 'Canceled'
             WHEN [Indication Date] IS NOT NULL AND 
                  ([Indication Date] > [Cancelled Date] OR [Cancelled Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Indication Date] > [Taken Date] OR [Taken Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Indication Date] > [Enquiry Date] OR [Enquiry Date] IS NULL) THEN 'Indication'        
             WHEN [Taken Date] IS NOT NULL AND 
                  ([Taken Date] > [Indication Date] OR [Indication Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Taken Date] > [Cancelled Date] OR [Cancelled Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Taken Date] > [Enquiry Date] OR [Enquiry Date] IS NULL) THEN 'Taken'        
             WHEN [Enquiry Date] IS NOT NULL AND 
                  ([Enquiry Date] > [Indication Date] OR [Indication Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Enquiry Date] > [Taken Date] OR [Taken Date] IS NULL) AND
                  ([Enquiry Date] > [Cancelled Date] OR [Cancelled Date] IS NULL) THEN 'Enquiry'        
        END            
FROM Sales
```

**EDIT:**

Here is some shortened version:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Sales
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                st
                      FROM      ( VALUES ( [Enquiry Date], 'Enquiry'),
                                ( [Taken Date], 'Taken'),
                                ( [Indication Date], 'Indication'),
                                ( [Cancelled Date], 'Canceled') ) d ( dt, st ) 
                      ORDER BY dt DESC
                    ) ca
```

Comment: Ya I dont think the developer had reporting in mind when he created the database.

Comment: OP requires "closest date to GETDATE()" not the maximum

Comment: Giorgi Can you explain how the CROSS APPLY works here. Iv not used it before

Comment: It is like an inner join. But cross apply body is evaluated for each row to the left of it. Here it is just for each row of a table picks the last date.